# Java & Type Erasure - How to generify MyClass.class from the string "MyClass"

Tags: java, class, generics, type-erasure

So I have a parameterized handler type where the type is a subclass of `MessageBase`.

```
public class ResponseHandler<T extends MessageBase> {

    private final T message;

    private ResponseHandler(final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.message = get(clazz);
    }

    public static <T extends MessageBase> ResponseHandler<T> of(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new ResponseHandler<>(clazz);
    }

    private T get(Class<T> clazz) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I also have a subset of `DerivedMessage` classes like `DerivedMessage1` and `DerivedMessage2` which both extend `MessageBase`. I want to be able to create the right `ResponseHandler` based on a string of the class name like this:

```
// defined some String s;
if (s == "com.package.DerivedMessage1") {
    ResponseHandler<DerivedMessage1> h1 = ResponseHandler.of(DerivedMessage1.class);
    // do something with h1
} else if (s == "com.package.DerivedMessage2") {
    ResponseHandler<DerivedMessage2> h2 = ResponseHandler.of(DerivedMessage2.class);
    // do something with h2
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to do this generically for all `DerivedMessage` classes, which derive from `MessageBase`. I haven't found a way to do the `DerivedMessage1.class` from a string like "com.package.DerivedMessage1". I've tried `Class.forName(string)`, but it returns a weird `capture ?` type that confuses me. Is there a way to accomplish this, or do I have to stick to the if statements?

Comment: What do you want to do after retrieving the "right" ResponseHandler instance? The generic types are only meaningful for the compiler, at runtime all T's will be Object (or in this case at least MessageBase) anyway. So what is wrong about a ResponseHandler<capture ?>, what can you not accomplish with it?

Comment: cant you use cast. Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) Class.forName(s);
        ResponseHandler<T> h = ResponseHandler.of(clazz);

Comment: to begin with, stop comparing Strings with `==`, then there is nothing weird with that "capture". And last point is "based on a string of the class", why? why can't it be based on a `Class`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getCanonicalName()`.

For example:
`DerivedMessage1.class.getCanonicalName()` returns `"com.package.DerivedMessage1"`

so the conditions becomes

```
if (DerivedMessage1.class. getCanonicalName().equals(s))) {
    ResponseHandler<DerivedMessage1> h1 = ResponseHandler.of(DerivedMessage1.class);
    // do something with h1
}
```

Comment: What? No that's not what I'm asking. I'm trying to make it so that I don't have to have an if condition for each `DerivedMessage` class. Something that takes the string of the class name, and just returns the correct `ResponseHandler`.

Comment: then you can use reflection like this `ResponseHandler.of(Class.forName(s).getConstructor().getNewInstance());`

Comment: This was giving me the error where it was expecting `?` but got `capture ?` instead. Or something like that. There's something about forName that it doesn't like.

Comment: `Class.forName(s).getConstructor().getNewInstance()` it returns the instance of the class supplied as parameter `s` so you don't need to deal with `cature ?` which tracks the meta information of the given class like constructs, properties, methods

Comment: how do I go from an instance of `MyClass` to a `MyClass.class`? That was the problem I was running into. It seems like it's impossible to do that generically.